# “unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE” and related messy stuff over mysql phpmyadmin 4.4.14 (X.A.M.P.P. 5.6.14-0-VC11, Windows 7 x64)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Already existent related question topics are useless, since it's a different (or even older -3.40-) version. So .patches don't even fit in files described in other posts around the web.

In addition to unknown table status these notices also appear every time I click over a non empty table:

Notice in .\libraries\tbl_info.inc.php#78
 Undefined index: Rows

Backtrace

```
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#221: include(.\libraries\tbl_info.inc.php)
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#85: PMA_Menu->_getBreadcrumbs()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#308: PMA_Menu->getHash()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#388: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
PMA_Response::response()
Notice in .\libraries\tbl_info.inc.php#80
 Undefined index: Name
```

Backtrace

```
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#221: include(.\libraries\tbl_info.inc.php)
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#85: PMA_Menu->_getBreadcrumbs()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#308: PMA_Menu->getHash()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#388: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
PMA_Response::response()
```

Notice in .\libraries\tbl_info.inc.php#78
 Undefined index: Rows

Backtrace

```
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#221: include(.\libraries\tbl_info.inc.php)
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#72: PMA_Menu->_getBreadcrumbs()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#315: PMA_Menu->getDisplay()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#388: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
PMA_Response::response()
Notice in .\libraries\tbl_info.inc.php#80
 Undefined index: Name
```

Backtrace

```
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#221: include(.\libraries\tbl_info.inc.php)
.\libraries\Menu.class.php#72: PMA_Menu->_getBreadcrumbs()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#315: PMA_Menu->getDisplay()
.\libraries\Response.class.php#388: PMA_Response->_ajaxResponse()
PMA_Response::response()
```

Any suggestion to avoid this annoying behaviour would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an outdated phpMyAdmin version. The latest stable version is 4.5.1. In the latest XAMPP (https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20151019.html) they mention updating phpMyAdmin to 4.5.0.2.